How serious is it for an artist-scholar with a professor role to misrepresent their achievements?
There is a senior figure (a professor and director of a research centre) at my institution who it seems has misrepresented their achievements and level of expertise in what seems to me to be quite a serious way.
This person is a fiction writer and scholar, however their experience as a fiction writer is quite minimal.  They've published some short stories in very minor journals and anthologies, and won some extremely minor awards - legitimate but very minor, of the level it's not uncommon to see students win.  They have worked in the publishing industry, but again in not very significant positions.  Their PhD project is in an unrelated field (education), and from what I can see they have no credible academic publications (journal articles, chapters etc).  From what I've been able to verify, they have one or two modest achievements of a level that you wouldn't expect to see from a student, but well below the level of national and international success you'd expect to see on the CV of a professor who is primarily a practitioner.
On a document which they've sent out to students, they claim that they won a significant international level award for short fiction, however I've looked into their claim and it doesn't hold up.  It seems they won a very minor award from a small organization and have misrepresented that award to make it appear of an elite international scale (I won't give the real organization but let's say they won an award from a small regional arts organization and have presented it as part of the Sunday Times Short Story Awards - it's comparable to that).
Their university staff page repeats that claim (with slightly more moderate language), and makes other fictional claims.  Again, I'll use comparable non-exact examples that exemplify their claims: let's say they claim to have had stories selected for the Pushcart Prize anthology and for the O.Henry Prize anthology - and that those claims are fictional.  It's comparable to that.
This person also won a substantial research grant recently, and it seems a realistic concern that these untruthful claims may have been repeated in their application.  At the very least the funder may have viewed their staff profile and been influenced.
It should also be said that on the same staff page they advertise their availability to supervise doctoral candidates - so doctoral researchers could conceivably spend their life savings to move to our city and pay their tuition to work with someone with these impressive accolades, only to find out they're fictional.
I think this is very serious, with the potential to bring my institution into disrepute. It's clear that any professor who fabricates, say, a journal article would be guilty of gross misconduct, so if a professor in an arts practice discipline fabricates a major award are they too guilty of gross misconduct, and if so how should someone who discovers gross misconduct of a senior colleague proceed?

It is, obviously, not acceptable to invent things on one's CV. It is a matter of debate whether the award from a small regional arts organization can be considered major or minor -- that's a judgment call every reader of a CV will have to make for themselves. Most people will simply list the award on their CV and leave the judging to the reader; most readers will consider it petty if the person whose CV we are talking about oversells the award as anything bigger than it is.
The question is whether you should do anything about it. You don't say what your relationship to the person in question is. Between the lines, I can guess that you're a colleague, and then the right course of action might be an informal conversation with the department head. You bring up your concerns, and whether anyone does anything about it is then in the hands of the authorities (the department head).
I will add, however, that people don't get hired on a whim. Your post suggests that you equate the embellishment of the CV with a lack of skills as a professor. That seems like a tenuous connection to me, for which you don't present any evidence. In practice, department hires -- at least in the countries I have worked in -- are highly scrutinized by many people, and those who do get hired are typically highly skilled in their area. I would therefore invite you to consider whether your attitude is basically a disagreement in value for this or that prize, or whether you can objectively back up your claim that that person is not actually skilled.

obviously if someone is fabricating awards to make themselves look more expert than they are then they are grossly incompetent for a professorial post and directorship of a research centre, posts for which maintaining institutional standards of ethics and integrity are core job requirements. In addition, this person's CV is full of misleading info, of course I haven't given evidence which would violate their privacy. Please read the question carefully, particularly if you're going to pick holes - the issues I highlighted are in a student-facing doc & staff profile, not CV.

Additionally, regarding professorial ability and your feeling that I was making a tenuous link between dishonesty and job skill, I will add, as I mentioned in another reply, that the reason I started looking into this person's credentials was because I had numerous complaints from students about their teaching and their conduct. Why they were hired is unknowable and irrelevant - many incompetent and disreputable people acquire positions of power.

Then, if you think that they are incompetent regarding the duties of the job, going to the department head (or perhaps an ombudsperson at your university, if you'd like to keep it lower profile) would be the logical next step.

@AnonymousAcademic444 Beware, it sounds like this person has a considerable position. Attempting to bring these concerns to light might cause significant backlash on you. This would, of course be unethical, but it might still happen, and you could find yourself in the moral right but unemployed.

Yes I agree, that's why I'm anonymously seeking guidance

More so than mere misrepresentation and breach of code of conduct that is to be understood primarily, it depends otherwise upon what the said achievements were, and are the said skillsets that would have been required for achieving said pedestals, have been attained by the professor in question already or not, upon which the integrity of the said achievements must have played certain role in the social capital of the person, is that all there was to their approval upon qualification? if not, then it is a qualitative analysis from thereon really, secondarily speaking.
